# Eclipse - Change default url in database set up

Tags: eclipse, oracle

In Eclipse I have problems connecting to a local oracle database, I went through `windows-perspective-database development`, added the oracle djbc driver, but when I get here

[image]

I can't change the connection url, even with correct username and password I'm unable to connect, I think it's because my url is `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE` and there is `jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:XE`. I can't change anything before the port 1521, how can i fix this?

Comment: `jdbc:oracle:thin` is the driver name; the other values are just copied from the other fields on the page. Trying changing the Host value from "server" to "localhost".

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do but i can't, i can only change `:XE`

Comment: You can't edit the field right below Connection URL? The one that says "Host: server"? It looks editable.

Comment: Yes, i missed that, entering `localhost` there fixed the issue.